# multiple inheritance in python and how to fix it

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance

I've always been told that multiple inheritance is a bad thing, so I've tried to avoid it. I didn't dig into why it's a problem.

I've recently come across a use of multiple inheritance in some python code that shows me why multiple inheritance is a bad thing. It seems to break the OOP concept of encapsulation. A simplified version of the code is as follows.

In a file called ClassA.py.

```
class ClassA:

    def randomMethodName(self):

        self.className = "A"

        print("I am ", self.className)
```

In a file called ClassB.py.

```
class ClassB:

    def doB(self):

        ###################################
        #
        #  I didn't import anything but I can access this.
        #
        ###################################
        self.randomMethodName()

    def doDifferentB(self):

        print("This is a different part of B")
```

In a file called ClassC.py.

```
class ClassC:

    def doC(self):
        ###################################
        #
        #  I didn't import anything but I can access this
        #
        ###################################
        self.randomMethodName()

    def doDifferentC(self):
        print("This is a different part of C")
```

In a file called ClassD.py.

```
from ClassA import ClassA
from ClassB import ClassB 
from ClassC import ClassC

class ClassD ( ClassA, ClassB, ClassC ):

    def doD(self):

        self.randomMethodName()
        self.doB()
        self.doDifferentB()
        self.doC()
        self.doDifferentC()
```

and then a simple driver.

```
#!/path/to/python/interpreter/python

from ClassD import ClassD

if __name__ == "__main__":

    d = ClassD()
    d.doD()
```

The output looks like:

```
I am A
I am A
This is a different part of B
I am A
This is a different part of C
```

Short of completely rewriting these classes, can anyone suggest how to make it clear that randomMethodName comes from ClassA when used in ClassB and ClassC?

Thanks,

Jason Mazzotta

Comment: The problem here isn't multiple inheritance. It's that `ClassB` and `ClassC` are calling a method that, as far as they are concerned, shouldn't exist. Most statically typed OOP languages wouldn't even admit this code. I would argue that, since `ClassB` and `ClassC` call a `ClassA` method, then *they* should both inherit from it in this case.

Comment: 1) What output would you want? 2) Why do you *care* where `randomMethodName` comes from?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, If ClassC and ClassB inherit from ClassA, then can ClassD still inherit from ClassA, ClassB and ClassC?

Comment: @chepner, 1)  I want the output to remain the same 2)  I don't care where randomMethodName comes from, I just want it to be obvious where it comes from.

Comment: If C and B both inherit from A, then D can inherit from B and C and get A indirectly. There's no reason, in that case, to have D inherit from A explicitly, since it will already be its grandparent class.